# How to define Security Rules based on another Document without loosing the ability to query them

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on a (knowledge)-graph application. I have the following collection structure

- /graphs/{id}/nodes/{id}
- /graphs/{id}/edges/{id}
- /graphs/{id}/users/{id}

The application should be able to listen realtime to new/updated nodes and edges in the graph. However one should only be able to read the node/edge if one has graph permission. Graph permission is evaluated by checking if a document for the logged in user exists under /graphs/{id}/users/{id}.

f.e like this:

```
match /graph/{grapId}/edges/{edgeID} {
  allow read: hasGraphPermission();
}
function hasGraphPermission() {
    exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/graphs/$(graphId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)
}
```

However as [security rules are no filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) this will not work if i want to query those edges/nodes. Which means i would lose realtime-updates on them.
I am a bit lost because I think this is a pretty common use-case and I am not sure if I miss  something here or if its really not possible.

Someone may able to help me out?

Hint: I not want to duplicated the information on the nodes/edges, as this potentially would lead to lots of writes whenever a user gets added/removed and the list of users can get large.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not so much in your security rules, but that queries in Firestore can only filter on data in the documents that it potentially returns. Since the `exists` condition checks on a document in another collection, it doesn't meet that requirement.

The common workaround is to duplicate the data that you want to filter on into the documents that you want to get back. Since you indicate not wanting to do that, it won't be possible to perform the query on Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though a bit disappointing this makes sense. If I conclude it in my own words, it effectively means that in firestore queries are only possible if all data, needed to check security against, is available on the document itself.
If someone else cares I am thinking to solve my use-case by having a public "update" collection where users can subscribe to, and then read individual documents seperately (including security-check). Not a perfect solution but may be good enough.